# Python, how can I concatenate 2 variables and create a name pointing to 3rd variable

Tags: python, automation

I would like to reduce my code and eliminate 3 `if` statements by joining together, in an `if` statement, 2 variables that if printed would create the name pointing to a 3rd variable.

Currently I have 3 `if` statements that look like this:

```
if prd.lower() not in retentions_log:
```

I would like to use something like:

```
if prd.lower() not in retentions_+prd.lower:
```

So every time the function is called It would construct the 3rd variable

> retentions+prd.lower = retentnions_log

This is one of the functions:

```
retentinon_approval_log = "SOME_VALUE"

def ret_handler_log(roletype, prd, pth, fnm, location):#                    [retention_proc]
    """Processors. 4Writing results to file."""
    if prd in retentinon_approval_log:
        if approval_check(roletype, prd, pth) == False:
            try:
                results_o.write("some_text")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                pass
        else:
            yaml_dumper(roletype, prd, location)
            results_o.write("some_text")
    else:
        yaml_dumper(roletype, prd, location)
```

> Update I'd like to be able to construct "retentinon_approval_+prd"
>   retentions approval being simple text and prd being "log". To
>   construct a variable "retentinon_approval_log" that points to "some
>   text" and dynamically generate this with different values that are
>   being passed to this function

Comment: _"Currently I have 3 if statements that look like this"_ and then you show one `if`. Show all of them.

Comment: @zvone I've updated the question with the real function

Comment: `if prd in retentinon_approval_log: if approval_check(roletype, prd, pth) == False:` is the same as `if prd in retentinon_approval_log and approval_check(roletype, prd, pth) == False:`. Is that what you asked for?

Comment: @zvone No
I am talking about `if prd in retentinon_approval_log:`
at this moment retentinon_approval_log is pointing to a variable as presented in the example.
I want to create with the variable "prd" and the simple text "retentinon_approval_" another variable, for example retentinon_approval_+prd ==> result in real life "retentinon_approval_blabla" and somwhere in the script retentinon_approval_blabla =  "a value whatever"

Comment: I have a feeling that I it cannot be done

Answer (score 1):

You may use a dictionary to build variables. Example.

```
d={'var1':10, 'var2':20}

d['var1'+'var2'] = d['var1'] + d['var2'] #{'var1': 10, 'var2': 20, 'var1var2': 30}
```

Comment: Thanks @newbie. I do not know the values of the variables as they change all the time. And I would like to just construct retentions_log as a variable that already exists. prd is a variable that changes all the time and "retentions_" is just text. By joining text + variable I would get the name of already existing variable, for example rententions_log='log' is already defined in the script I just need to find a way to call it instead of using if statements (retentions_log, retentions_metric and retentions_tmt already exist in the python code )

Comment: If you show a better example in your question, I can improve the answer with a better example as well.